# Driving distance and travel time duration between two locations

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio, import

I'm doing an android application which I need to find Distance & travel time 
between two locations by giving two lat/lang points in android mapV2.
I'm using the example as [Driving distance and travel time duration between two locations in Google Map Android API V2](http://androidmapv2.blogspot.com/2013/11/driving-distance-and-travel-time.html)

I am getting too many errors and typos  in this code, please help me to   resolve this problem.

I am using android key will it work on google places api and direction api or not??

**Manifest:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="">

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

        <uses-feature
            android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
                android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

**Main Actvity:**

```
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

        GoogleMap map;
        ArrayList<LatLng> markerPoints;
        TextView tvDistanceDuration;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            tvDistanceDuration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_distance_time);

            // Initializing
            markerPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

            // Getting reference to SupportMapFragment of the activity_main
            SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

            // Getting Map for the SupportMapFragment
            map = fm.getMap();

            // Enable MyLocation Button in the Map
            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            // Setting onclick event listener for the map
            map.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

                    // Already two locations
                    if(markerPoints.size()>1){
                        markerPoints.clear();
                        map.clear();
                    }

                    // Adding new item to the ArrayList
                    markerPoints.add(point);

                    // Creating MarkerOptions
                    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

                    // Setting the position of the marker
                    options.position(point);

                    /**
                     * For the start location, the color of marker is GREEN and
                     * for the end location, the color of marker is RED.
                     */
                    if(markerPoints.size()==1){
                        options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
                    }else if(markerPoints.size()==2){
                        options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
                    }


                    // Add new marker to the Google Map Android API V2
                    map.addMarker(options);

                    // Checks, whether start and end locations are captured
                    if(markerPoints.size() >= 2){
                        LatLng origin = markerPoints.get(0);
                        LatLng dest = markerPoints.get(1);

                        // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
                        String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin, dest);

                        DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

                        // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
                        downloadTask.execute(url);
                    }

                }
            });

        }

        private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin,LatLng dest){

            // Origin of route
            String str_origin = "origin="+origin.latitude+","+origin.longitude;

            // Destination of route
            String str_dest = "destination="+dest.latitude+","+dest.longitude;


            // Sensor enabled
            String sensor = "sensor=false";

            // Building the parameters to the web service
            String parameters = str_origin+"&"+str_dest+"&"+sensor;

            // Output format
            String output = "json";

            // Building the url to the web service
            String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+output+"?"+parameters;


            return url;
        }

        /** A method to download json data from url */
        private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
            String data = "";
            InputStream iStream = null;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            try{
                URL url = new URL(strUrl);

                // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                // Connecting to url
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Reading data from url
                iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

                StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

                String line = "";
                while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                    sb.append(line);
                }

                data = sb.toString();

                br.close();

            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
            }finally{
                iStream.close();
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            return data;
        }



        // Fetches data from url passed
        private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

            // Downloading data in non-ui thread
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

                // For storing data from web service
                String data = "";

                try{
                    // Fetching the data from web service
                    data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
                }
                return data;
            }

            // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
            // doInBackground()
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

                // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
                parserTask.execute(result);

            }
        }


        private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> >{

            // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
            @Override
            protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

                JSONObject jObject;
                List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

                try{
                    jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
                    DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

                    // Starts parsing data
                    routes = parser.parse(jObject);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return routes;
            }

            // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
                ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
                PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                String distance = "";
                String duration = "";



                if(result.size()<1){
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Points", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }


                // Traversing through all the routes
                for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
                    points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                    lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

                    // Fetching i-th route
                    List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

                    // Fetching all the points in i-th route
                    for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
                        HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j);

                        if(j==0){    // Get distance from the list
                            distance = (String)point.get("distance");
                            continue;
                        }else if(j==1){ // Get duration from the list
                            duration = (String)point.get("duration");
                            continue;
                        }

                        double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                        double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                        LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                        points.add(position);
                    }

                    // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
                    lineOptions.addAll(points);
                    lineOptions.width(2);
                    lineOptions.color(Color.RED);

                }

                tvDistanceDuration.setText("Distance:"+distance + ", Duration:"+duration);

                // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
                map.addPolyline(lineOptions);
            }
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }
    }


    **Directionjasonparser.java:**


    public class DirectionsJSONParser {

        public List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> parse(JSONObject jObject){

            List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = new ArrayList<List<HashMap<String,String>>>() ;
            JSONArray jRoutes = null;
            JSONArray jLegs = null;
            JSONArray jSteps = null;
            JSONObject jDistance = null;
            JSONObject jDuration = null;

            try {

                jRoutes = jObject.getJSONArray("routes");

                /** Traversing all routes */
                for(int i=0;i<jRoutes.length();i++){
                    jLegs = ( (JSONObject)jRoutes.get(i)).getJSONArray("legs");

                    List<HashMap<String, String>> path = new                 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                    /** Traversing all legs */
                    for(int j=0;j<jLegs.length();j++){

                        /** Getting distance from the json data */
                        jDistance = ((JSONObject) jLegs.get(j)).getJSONObject("distance");
                        HashMap<String, String> hmDistance = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        hmDistance.put("distance", jDistance.getString("text"));

                        /** Getting duration from the json data */
                        jDuration = ((JSONObject) jLegs.get(j)).getJSONObject("duration");
                        HashMap<String, String> hmDuration = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        hmDuration.put("duration", jDuration.getString("text"));

                        /** Adding distance object to the path */
                        path.add(hmDistance);

                        /** Adding duration object to the path */
                        path.add(hmDuration);


                        jSteps = ( (JSONObject)jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray("steps");


                        for(int k=0;k<jSteps.length();k++){
                            String polyline = "";


                      polyline = (String)((JSONObject)((JSONObject)jSteps.get(k)).get("polyline")).get("points");


      List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(polyline);

                            /** Traversing all points */
                            for(int l=0;l<list.size();l++){
                                HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                hm.put("lat", Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).latitude) );
                                hm.put("lng", Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).longitude) );
                                path.add(hm);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    routes.add(path);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (Exception e){
            }

            return routes;
        }

        private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

            List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
            int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
            int lat = 0, lng = 0;

            while (index < len) {
                int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
                do {
                    b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                    result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                    shift += 5;
                } while (b >= 0x20);
                int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
                lat += dlat;

                shift = 0;
                result = 0;
                do {
                    b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                    result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                    shift += 5;
                } while (b >= 0x20);
                int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
                lng += dlng;

                LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                        (((double) lng / 1E5)));
                poly.add(p);
            }

            return poly;
        }
    }
```

**Activity_main.xml:**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_distance_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hello_world"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_below="@id/tv_distance_time" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use the  [Google Maps Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro#Introduction) to get travel distance and time for a matrix of origins and destinations. The information returned is based on the recommended route between start and end points.

Here's a sample request, 'HTTPS' is recommended for applications that include sensitive user data, such as user's location: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/output?parameters

You must register your app on Google Developers Console and get a Google API key which you can add to your app: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup

Comment: The second link is broken.

Comment: Mahendra Gunawardena yeah i know, How can i connect this link ? through Android Api kie or Server key, please help me i m running out of time...